# Is UINavigationController fullscreen only?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uinavigationcontroller

I'm working from the Navigation-based Application template for iPad. I need a NavigationController presenting my playlist hierachy in a TableView.

Works out of the book. No problem.

[image: Full Screen Navigaton Controller.]

Now I want this view to take only part of the screen, so, in my AppDelegate I say:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    self.window.rootViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,352,384,1024-352);
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

This works. However, now the title bar overlaps part of the TableView.

[image: Crooked title bar when not fullscreen.]

I could move the table view downwards, but this would make the "pop-in" animation of the next view coming in look somewhat strange, because the animation will return to the overlapping version, then animate, then de-overlap after the animation has finished.

I'm looking for a way to move the title bar of the NC up. Any ideas?

Comment: I do something similar too, but chose move the table view downwards. The pop-in animation isn't that bad, it's barely noticeable unless you're specifically looking for it I guess?

Comment: I did it with some hacking. It's a nightmare when device is being rotated. You'll have to compensate each time you flip the device and `-viewWillAppear`. Avoid it at all cost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just set resize rootViewController since the screen will has empty areas!
You may try to use [UISplitController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISplitViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) or start with empty view application template and then add UIView objects as many as you want to your XIB file and layout them out as you desire then add a UINavigationController to one of them instead of rootViewController.

Comment: Negative. It is not recommended but totally feasible. It's dark side of `InterfaceBuilder` that makes people forget how things actually work.

Comment: @bioffe definitely i agree with you, but InterfaceBuilder is much easier to use and to follow MVC design pattern.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
self.window.rootViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,384,1024-352);
```